# cp: cannot stat '/opt/flink/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-*.jar': No such file or directory in apache flink

Tags: kubernetes

I am upgrade apache flink 1.10 to apache flink 1.11 in kubernetes, but the jobmanager kubernetes pod log shows:

```
cp: cannot stat '/opt/flink/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-*.jar': No such file or directory
```

this is my jobmanager pod yaml:

```
kind: Deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: report-flink-jobmanager
  namespace: middleware
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/middleware/deployments/report-flink-jobmanager
  uid: b7bd8f0d-cddb-44e7-8bbe-b96e68dbfbcd
  resourceVersion: '13655071'
  generation: 44
  creationTimestamp: '2020-06-08T02:11:33Z'
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: report-flink
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: flink
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.10.0
    component: jobmanager
    helm.sh/chart: flink-0.1.15
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: '6'
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: report-flink
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: middleware
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: report-flink
      app.kubernetes.io/name: flink
      component: jobmanager
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: report-flink
        app.kubernetes.io/name: flink
        component: jobmanager
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: flink-config-volume
          configMap:
            name: report-flink-config
            items:
              - key: flink-conf.yaml
                path: flink-conf.yaml.tpl
              - key: log4j.properties
                path: log4j.properties
              - key: security.properties
                path: security.properties
            defaultMode: 420
        - name: flink-pro-persistent-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: flink-pv-claim
      containers:
        - name: jobmanager
          image: 'flink:1.11'
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - '-c'
            - >-
              cp /opt/flink/opt/flink-metrics-prometheus-*.jar
              /opt/flink/opt/flink-s3-fs-presto-*.jar /opt/flink/lib/ && wget
              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/oshi/oshi-core/3.4.0/oshi-core-3.4.0.jar
              -O /opt/flink/lib/oshi-core-3.4.0.jar && wget
              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna/5.4.0/jna-5.4.0.jar
              -O /opt/flink/lib/jna-5.4.0.jar && wget
              https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/java/dev/jna/jna-platform/5.4.0/jna-platform-5.4.0.jar
              -O /opt/flink/lib/jna-platform-5.4.0.jar && cp
              $FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml.tpl
              $FLINK_HOME/conf/flink-conf.yaml && $FLINK_HOME/bin/jobmanager.sh
              start; while :; do if [[ -f $(find log -name '*jobmanager*.log'
              -print -quit) ]]; then tail -f -n +1 log/*jobmanager*.log; fi;
              done
          workingDir: /opt/flink
          ports:
            - name: blob
              containerPort: 6124
              protocol: TCP
            - name: rpc
              containerPort: 6123
              protocol: TCP
            - name: ui
              containerPort: 8081
              protocol: TCP
            - name: metrics
              containerPort: 9999
              protocol: TCP
          env:
            - name: JVM_ARGS
              value: '-Djava.security.properties=/opt/flink/conf/security.properties'
            - name: FLINK_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: APOLLO_META
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: pro-config
                  key: apollo.meta
            - name: ENV
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: pro-config
                  key: env
          resources: {}
          volumeMounts:
            - name: flink-config-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/conf/flink-conf.yaml.tpl
              subPath: flink-conf.yaml.tpl
            - name: flink-config-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/conf/log4j.properties
              subPath: log4j.properties
            - name: flink-config-volume
              mountPath: /opt/flink/conf/security.properties
              subPath: security.properties
            - name: flink-pro-persistent-storage
              mountPath: /opt/flink/data/
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 6124
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 15
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 6123
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 1
            periodSeconds: 10
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
          terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
          terminationMessagePolicy: File
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      restartPolicy: Always
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      serviceAccountName: jobmanager
      serviceAccount: jobmanager
      securityContext: {}
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
status:
  observedGeneration: 44
  replicas: 1
  updatedReplicas: 1
  unavailableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
    - type: Available
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2020-08-19T06:26:56Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-08-19T06:26:56Z'
      reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
      message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    - type: Progressing
      status: 'False'
      lastUpdateTime: '2020-08-19T06:42:56Z'
      lastTransitionTime: '2020-08-19T06:42:56Z'
      reason: ProgressDeadlineExceeded
      message: >-
        ReplicaSet "report-flink-jobmanager-7b8b9bd6bb" has timed out
        progressing.
```

should I remove the not exists jar file? how to fix this?

Comment: You should probably create a Docker image that contains this software preinstalled, rather than having every restart of every replica attempt three external network calls or fail.

Comment: How did you upgrade it? This cluster is on your local env?

Comment: this cluster is in the cloud, I want to upgrade it just change the image name. but I read the official document, the new version has no helm chart and change so much content and it is hard to upgrade just change a image name. Now I am reinstall it@PjoterS

Comment: Did reinstall help? Do you still have the same issue or different?